# How to fetch the value saved in NSUserdefault

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use NSUser Deafault in my application user have tp fillup 4 UITextFields. I am trying to save the fields so that on subsequent runs of the program that whatever they previously put will already be displayed in those UITextFields so the wont have to re-input it in - unless they want to edit something in which case they still have that option. I think that I have figured out a good way to save the strings using NSUserDefaults but now I am trying to figure out how to have those fields populate a UITextField - it doesnt seem as easy as if they were UILabels. This is the route I am attempting:

Now my value is being saved in nsuserDefalut,but hot how to fetch dat value next time(when i re start application (null appear on the uitext field)) ..I am trying this cods

NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; //Hooks.
    NSString *placeHolderName = [userData stringForKey:@"name"];
    urltextFieldNormal.text = placeHolderName;

Comment: That code is correct; how are you storing the value?

Comment: i no this cod e is correct but how can i see the value when i restart the applicatuon i mean how to fetch the key value...kind provide me appropriate code
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you remember to sync NSUserDefaults when you save the strings?

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Hello mister nick" forKey:@"alarmsArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Cheers mate...